# Start GUI application in an RDP session from a different session in Windows

Tags: java, windows, session, powershell, rdp

**Context:**
All I want to do is, start a GUI application (ex: mspaint) on Windows node (spawned on cloud) using Java and when I connect using RDP, I want the GUI application to be already there.

**Issue:**
After connecting to the remote Windows node through RDP, I don't see the GUI application already there.
I can see that my Java program has actually started GUI application and I can see that in the tasks list. It got started under "Services" session. When I run the same Java program after connecting to RDP, it started the same application in session with name "RDP-Tcp#0"

If I am using traditional RDP client, I can simply choose the session I want to connect to but here I have no control as I am using HTML5 RDP client called Guacamole.

Java program uses Runtime.getRuntime().exec() API to run a powershell script thats starts the GUI application.

Is there a way to run my script so that it runs and shows the GUI on a different session? This is trivial in Linux where we need to simply export the DISPLAY env variable.

Please help

Comment: What exatcly do you run to remote execute your java code ?

Comment: From the post, it seems like the Java process is not started remotely, but from something on the host. Am I right? If a Windows service is actually launching your Java application, and the host OS is Windows 7 or above, there is no way to have the UI visible. There are other means, though, which I can explain if I'm on the right track...

Comment: @Poorkenny Yes, Java program resides on the host and gets called on startup. OS is Windows 2008 server R2 with SP1. Please help on the probable way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start a program in an RDP session that doesn't exist yet. To get what you want to work you'd need your code to actually log in via RDP, start the program, and then disconnect the session without logging off. However, since idle sessions eat up system resources, Terminal Server admins tend to set a timeout for idle sessions after which the user is automatically logged out.